# Separate the given numeric values from column of the dataframe? (df[‘col1]) = [‘a_1’,’b_2’,’c_3’,’d_4’]

Tags: python, pandas

** task is to separate the numbers from the each element of respective row from pandas dataframe

column name is col1 and column contains elements in form of list

[‘a_1’,’b_2’,’c_3’,’d_4’] **

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do this at least these two ways:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = ['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_4']
df
```

Input dataframe:

```
  col1
0  a_1
1  b_2
2  c_3
3  d_4
```

#### Option 1, using .str.split:

```
df['col1'].str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
```

#### Option 2, using .str.extract with regex:

```
df['col1'].str.extract('\_(\d+)')
```

Output:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = [['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_4']]
```

Input:

```
                   col1
0  [a_1, b_2, c_3, d_4]
```

Doing:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [i.split('_')[1] for i in x])
```

Output:

```
           col1
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```